# Split the Pentominoes

Tags: geometry, polyomino

<sub>[Source](http://www.puzzles.com/puzzleplayground/PentominoProblem/PentominoProblem.htm)</sub>

The image below shows a solved [pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) puzzle in a $6\times10$ grid.

[image: Start]

Your challenge is to divide the rectangle along the black lines only to make two pieces that can be rearranged and fit together again to make the $7\times9$ rectangle below with three holes in it.

[image: Finish]

Comment: Do you make the colored pentomino pattern in any software? Or just Paint-craft?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I used MS Excel, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the rectangle along a jagged line from the bottom left to the top right into two approximate triangles:

> ```
> PPPLIIIII
> PPSLLLL
> SSSNNN
> SFNN
> FFF
> F
>
>         T
>       TTT
>      XUUT
>    WXXXUV
>   YWWXUUV
> YYYYWWVVV
> ```

Shifting the bottom-right triangle down and left one unit from its original location, we get a new 7x9 rectangle with three holes:

> ```
> PPPLIIIII
> PPSLLLL.T
> SSSNNNTTT
> SFNN.XUUT
> FFFWXXXUV
> F.YWWXUUV
> YYYYWWVVV
> ```

Comment: Can you edit to add an explanation to your answer? This is a bit incomprehensible at the moment.

Comment: I edited it. I hope that helps. BTW, I always forget how to do preformatted text in spoilers. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's alright ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Not wanting to submit this as the correct answer but hoping to add clarification...  @JaapScherphuis seems to have this one correct.  The answer actually seemed a bit too obvious to me though...

> [image]
>
>  The shapes to the bottom right of the original image have been cut and moved down and left, each by one square.

Comment: You're right that it's not too hard of a puzzle. I just liked the idea of pentominoes.